# How to set alias .\ for LocalDb?

Tags: localdb

I have installed LocalDb 15.0.4153.1 on my new development machine. It has been installed with Visual Studio 2022 on the fly. The setup created a default instance being called "MSSQLLocalDB". It works. I can connect with "(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB" successfully.

However, on my other development machines I am able to access the instance with ".\" instead of "(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB".

How can I access LocalDb with ".\" on my new development machine as well? I need the same behaviour on all of my machines.

Comment: Where do you put ".\" ? Can you give your connection scripts?

Comment: I guess that you are not accessing localdb on the other machines

Comment: @ErikEJ: oh, oh. I guess you are right. I probably have SQL Express on the other machines. I need to check this next and will report back asap.

Comment: @Kendle: Well, if I use a tool like MS SQL Server Management Studio, all it takes is "\." in the "Connect to Server" dialog. If I want to access my databases by code, the connection string looks like "Server=.\;Database=myDatabase;Integrated Security=True"

Comment: Good morning. Jeez. It's even worse. I have "MS SQL Server Developer" on my other machines. I was so sure it is LocalDb. So, case closed. Sorry for the trouble, guys. Thank you!